# C# Whats better practice? Validating Form input through properties, or on the click (add) event

Tags: c#, forms, properties, exception, try-catch

General question of whats better practice?

Say if I am receiving integer input ( and need to test for "not null" and an integer) is it better to do this in the class properties?

Seem silly to do on click event, but im asking because of needing to prompt the user (in exception handling)

Comment: are you trying to retrieve what is selected in the combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string name = TxtName.Text;
Contract ct = (Contract)Enum.Parse(typeof(CarCategory), name, false);
```